# CRM 2011 How to create a public view with a "group by"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to create a public view for an entity that has a "group by" field. Not a problem when I make a private view, I just click on View Settings and setup a group by. However, when creating a new public view, those options don't exist! Is there no way to add a "group by" for public views?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just share your private view with all users?

Comment: I'd like the view to be part of the solution file I'm building. But yes, for now, I'm sharing my private view.